# meaning of suffix in hunspell files i.e. `/EPSozm`

Tags: file-format, hunspell, dict

When I grep for `phan` in my hunspell-dic file /usr/share/hunspell/de_DE_frami.dic, I get list of words including

```
cellophan/Sozm
cellophan/hke
cellophan/ozm
glaukophan/EPSozm
```

Where do I find documentation, what the suffixes mean? I looked for a manpage for hunspell but only found a non helpful one to update-dictcommon-hunspell. `man dict?` didn't help either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's hunspell-specific, so `man dict` not giving much information is not surprising! `man 5 hunspell` contains the information on what these flags mean. My distro doesn't ship that man page, so [here's](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man4/hunspell.4.html) a link.

> Hunspell  requires  two  files  to  define  the way a language is being spell checked: a dictionary file containing words and applicable flags, and an affix file  that specifies how these flags will control spell checking.

So, we're looking at the *dictionary file*, and we see some flags, but what they mean is undefined without looking at the *affix file*.

The syntax of both seems to be involved; I've not understood it.

Comment: The man page is in section 5 now.

Comment: @StephenKitt Ah! My Fedora ships neither with hunspell, but includes the section 5 manpage in `hunspell-devel`.

Comment: My distro, Xubuntu, doesn't ship with the manpage either, and wow, that looks complicated and elaborated - nothing I would like to lookup by hand. But now I have at least a rough estimation, what these affixes might provide. Thx.

Comment: Well, German might be the least nice to compactly represent indogermanic language when it comes to flexation – making these flags so numerous and "powerful"; of that, you can *selbstvergewissern* :D